# Adjust size of leaflet map in rmarkdown html

Tags: html, r, leaflet, markdown

I'd like to change the height and width of `leaflet` map outputs in html document. Is there a simple way to do this in R markdown without getting into whole CSS business?

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

m <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 12)
m %>% addTiles() 
```
````

Ideally, I want the width of map to be the same width of code block as shown below.

[image]

Comment: have you tried this ```{r, fig.width = 8.5, fig.height = 5.5}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set like a global figure size to the whole document... But I think your code chunks will rescale, the images not.

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8)
```

Actually, I didn't checked it with `leaflets`. Hope this code is still working.

Answer (score 34):

I found that changing `fig.width` and `fig.height` did not change the size of my leaflet maps. However, changing a different parameter/option did.

Try changing the width/height using this in the header for the code chunk:

`{r, width = 40, height = 30}`

Or alternatively, another thing that has worked for me is to use this (in this case, do not put anything in the chunk header:

`m <- leaflet(width = "100%") %>%`

Comment: You may also want to use `out.width` in the chunk options.

Comment: To add @Sébastien Rochette, `{r, out.width = '100%'}` worked for me

Comment: none of the options show here worked for me *except* for `{r, out.width = '100%'}` by @SébastienRochette

Answer (score 4):

This works fine:

```
SomeData %>% 
  leaflet(height=2000, width=2000) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

Here SomeData is a dataframe containing columns: Lat and Long.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the other answers:

My understanding is that `fig.width` and `fig.height` don't work for `leaflet` (or `plotly`) because they are html objects, not 'true figures' as far as `knitr` is concerned. `leaflet` (and `plotly`) do however respond to `out.width`, which is why it works.

In case anyone ever has a similar situation to me:

I have a code chunk which conditionally includes either a `leaflet` map (for html output), or 4x saved `ggplot` .png images using `knitr::include_graphics(p1, p2, p3, p4)` (for pdf output). In order to tile the 4 `ggplot` objects in a 2x2 grid, I had to set `out.width = '50%'`, but this also reduced the width of the `leaflet` output.

The solution was to include `leaflet(width = '100%')` in the code, and `out.width = '50%'` in the chunk header. `leaflet(width = '100%')` seems to override `out.width = '50%'`, giving me either a full sized `leaflet` in html outputs, or 50% width `ggplot` figures.